# Rolling 7 with two dice?

Tags: probability, dice

> In certain board game, two fair dice are rolled. If a pair of the same number is obtained, the dice are rolled for the second time. The player continues rolling those two dice and he stops when the numbers turn up on the dice are different. Evaluate the probability that a player obtains a total of seven points when he rolls the dice as described.

I answered this twice and got it wrong. Can anyone please help me?

PS This lesson is about bayes theorem so that might help a little.

EDIT: It said the answer is $\frac{3997}{23328}$.

Comment: Ordinarily when we talk about rolling two dice, we imagine one of the dice is red and the other is blue so we have the convenient equiprobable sample space $\{(1,1),(1,2),\dots,(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)\}$ where the first number in the pair is the red and the second is the blue.  Here in this case, we are essentially restricting our sample space to those outcomes where the numbers in the pair are not the same.  How many ways can you add up to $7$ with two dice?  How many ways can you not have rolled a pair?  Take the ratio.

Comment: Can you post your two attempts so we can pinpoint where you are making a mistake?  That will be far more valuable than us just doing this problem for you.

Comment: "I answered this twice and got it wrong" Please include what you answered and how you arrived at the answer you arrived at. At present, your question has zero context...

Comment: Going by the posted Answer, how weird of a number that is, and how close it is to $\frac{1}{6}$, I am guessing that the 'total' is not the total from the last roll, but the total of all rolls. So, for example, the total would be 7 if the person rolls 1,1, followed by 2,3. So maybe you were assuming that the 'total' was the total of just the last roll? (that's what I did when reading the question, but apparently that's not what the question meant)

Comment: Unfortunately so @Bram28... and that answer checks out.  That being said, the question is very poorly worded as the simpler of the questions is the one that most people would immediately assume is the intended.

Comment: @JMoravitz Agreed! A poorly worded question ...

Comment: I don't think the wording is that poor. The rules state that you throw two dice. Then, in some cases you throw them again. From the phrase "a total of seven points" I would automatically assume that we sum up the doubles as we go and add them to the last (non-double) throw. If you still want to get nit-picky  about implicitly assumed details, who said it was regular $1$-$6$-dice, or that the total number of dots on the upper face of the dice were what counted as points?

Answer (score 3):

> In certain board game, two fair dice are rolled. If a pair of the same number is obtained, the dice are rolled for the second time. The player continues rolling those two dice and he stops when the numbers turn up on the dice are different. Evaluate the probability that a player **obtains a total of seven points** when he rolls the dice as described.

There are apparently two interpretations of this statement, and I will discuss the probabilities associated with each.  It is not made perfectly clear from the question how exactly the points are calculated.

- **Possibility 1:  The points are just counted from the final roll and no other rolls matter.**

E.g. The sequence of rolls $(1,1),(1,1),(1,2)$ would end in a failure since the "total" here would be $1+2=3$ whereas the sequence of rolls $(1,1),(3,4)$ would be considered a success since the final roll $(3,4)$ has $3+4=7$.

Under this interpretation, we may use a conditional probability argument to convince ourselves that we may look instead at the restricted sample space $\{(1,2),(1,3),\dots,(2,1),(2,3),\dots,(6,4),(6,5)\}$ which has only $30$ members, six of which correspond to success.  This would have the probability be then $\frac{6}{30}=0.2$

> If it is hard to convince yourself of this, then you may approach in a more tedious way: letting $p$ be the probability of rolling doubles on a specific roll and $q$ the probability of success on a specific roll, i.e. $p=q=1/6$, we would have the probability as $=q+pq+p^2q+p^3q+\dots+p^nq+\dots = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{6^3}+\dots = \frac{1/6}{1-1/6}=0.2$, same answer as before

---

- **Possibility 2: The points are counted from all rolls combined**

E.g. the sequence of rolls $(1,1),(1,1),(1,2)$ would end in a *success* this time since the "total" here would be $1+1+1+1+1+2=7$ whereas the sequence of rolls $(1,1),(3,4)$ would be considered a *failure* since the total here is $1+1+3+4=9$.

Under this interpretation, we use a great deal more casework.  Fortunately, the desired total is small and we are guaranteed to have won or lost by the third roll.

The possibilities:

- Win on the first roll
- Win on the second roll after having rolled (1,1)
- Win on the second roll after having rolled (2,2)
- Win on the third roll after having rolled (1,1) twice in a row

Convince yourself that there are no other possibilities.  We could not for example win after having rolled $(3,3)$ on the first turn because the total would be $3+3+\dots+a+b>7$.

So then, we continue by counting probabilities and combining for a final total probability of:

$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{36}\cdot\frac{4}{36} + \frac{1}{36}\cdot\frac{2}{36}+\frac{1}{36}\cdot\frac{1}{36}\cdot\frac{2}{36} = \frac{3997}{23328}$$

The terms in the above are calculated directly via multiplication principle and direct counting.  For example, the final term corresponds to rolling a (1,1) followed by a (1,1) followed by something which adds to three (*noting that no combination that adds to three will result in a pair*).

Comment: Thanks for you detailed explanation. I think the question is not set up very clearly.